# Unable to center the text in textview

Tags: android, textview

I am using following code to center the text in textview.

```
<TextView android:layout_height="20dp" 
android:layout_width="20dp" 
android:text="?"
android:id="@+id/tv281"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:background="@drawable/qcircle"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
></TextView>
```

But the "?" is not vertically centered. What is wrong ?

Comment: share your complete layout

Comment: Share the screen of how it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is already centered vertically, but the layout height is too small, or textSize too big, change that

**edit**

this is better

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

the problem is that the text font is too big for the layout height, then you can change this values, but also the problem is the padding of the layout, if you put android:padding="0dp" won't work, because the padding of the font, the best solution is not to include de font's padding in the TextView

Comment: for me reducing the size of text was enough to get the result.